# Is "Hydrolyzed Vegetable Protein" (HVP) vegan?

Tags: veganism, is-it-vegan, protein, science

Is [Hydrolyzed Vegetable Protein (HVP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrolyzed_vegetable_protein) vegan?

The name suggests that *maybe* it's derived wholly from vegetables, but the following snippet from Wikipedia is concerning:

> Hydrolyzed vegetable protein (HVP) products are foodstuffs obtained by protein hydrolysis and are used as ingredients to create a bouillon (broth) taste without the vegetables, bones...
>
> Today, it is made mainly from protein resources of vegetable origin

If I see something has HVP in it, can I be certain that it does not contain animals or animal byproducts?

Answer (score 1):

While Hydrolyzed Vegetable Protein (HVP) is typically made from vegetable sources and considered vegan, it’s still a good idea to double-check the label or reach out to the manufacturer or customer care to make sure that no animal products or byproducts were used in its production.